# Pycharm running Kivy applications

Tags: python, interpreter, pycharm, kivy

I'm running Pycharm 3.4.1 and i just downloaded the Kivy 1.8.0 for python 2.7 pack for windows.
http://kivy.org/#download

I chose the kivy interpreter as my python interpreter for the project:

```
C:\Python_Kivy_1.8.0\Python27\python.exe
```

The problem i'm having is that i can't get my Pycharm to run or recognize Kivy at all. There is no auto-completion when writing code and it can't execute via Pycharm. The only way i can execute the program is by running the python file with the kivy.bat file, and that is anoying to do every time.

When i'm trying to execute the code via pycharm i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Victor/Dropbox/Private/filewatcher_gui/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
ImportError: No module named kivy

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can't you install `Kivy` with `pip` directly in existing python ? Then you will not have to change interpreter.

Comment: BTW: In PyCharm `File > Settings > Python Interpretter` you can install new modules in existing interpreter.

Comment: It's certainly possible to install kivy in existing python, but we provide the package because we include cython code and use some dependencies that can be difficult to install this way, such as (as I remember) pygame. So it can work, but it's probably harder than just a pip install command.

Answer (score 2):

The kivy wiki has some pages on configuring for different ides, including [pycharm](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE%27s).

You could also probably install in your existing installation using the (unofficial) prebuilt windows packages [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Make sure to get kivy's dependencies as well if you try this way.